# Why do I get a syntax error when I want to print to a handle in a hash key?

Tags: perl, syntax-error, filehandle

I have code which stores all the files handles for files in the current directory as values in a hash. The keys are the names of the files.

```
my %files_list;    #this is a global variable.
sub create_hash() {
    opendir my $dir, "." or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
    my @files = readdir $dir;
    foreach (@files) {
        if (/.text/) {
            open(PLOT, ">>$_") || die("This file will not open!");
            $files_list{$_} = *PLOT;
        }
    }
}
```

Down the line I am using print statements in my code where I am facing some compilation issues.

```
my $domain = $_;
opendir my $dir, "." or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
my @files = readdir $dir;
foreach (@files) {
    if (/.text/ && /$subnetwork2/) {
        print $files_list{$_} "$domain";    #this is line 72 where there is error.
    }
}
closedir $dir;
```

The compilation errors are below:

```
String found where operator expected at process.pl line 72, near "} "$domain""
        (Missing operator before  "$domain"?)
syntax error at process.pl line 72, near "} "$domain""
```

Could anyone please help me understand the fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first problem:
After running `create_hash` subroutine you would have `%files_list` filled up with `*PLOT` in all keys.

all `print {$files_list{$_}} "$domain";` whould print into last opened file.
solution:

```
-open(PLOT,">>$_") || die("This file will not open!");
-$files_list{$_}=*PLOT;
+open($files_list{$_},">>$_") || die("This file will not open!");
```

second problem:
you don't check that file descriptor exists before printing into it
solution:

```
-if(/.text/ && /$subnetwork2/)
-{
-    print $files_list{$_} "$domain";#this is line 72 where there is error.
+if(/.text/ && /$subnetwork2/ && exists $files_list{$_})
+{
+    print {$files_list{$_}} $domain;
```

and don't forget about closing file handles...

Comment: Also 3-argument form of open is a nice habit: `open ($fd, '>>', $_)`

Comment: You should really use lexical filehandles for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should read the [documentation for print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html). The final paragraph says:

> If you're storing handles in an array or hash, or in general whenever
>   you're using any expression more complex than a bareword handle or a
>   plain, unsubscripted scalar variable to retrieve it, you will have to
>   use a block returning the filehandle value instead, in which case the
>   LIST may not be omitted:
>
> ```
> print { $files[$i] } "stuff\n";
> print { $OK ? STDOUT : STDERR } "stuff\n";
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe as this:

```
print {$files_list{$_}} "$domain";
```